# How to use CLN : Class Library for Numbers

Tags: numerical

I need to do numerical calculations with high precision. There is a c++ library which is called "CLN",although i installed this package , but i do not know how to use it.
Is there an example program which shows how to use it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

http://www.warrenweckesser.net/software/cln/

Comment: Thanks. Yes i want examples like this. are there any more examples like  this one?

Comment: I haven't been using much of them, but I'm sure that google search will bring you more :)

Comment: Sadly, I let my domain registration lapse years ago, and my domain name was taken over by some sort of ad company.  Now I see that it displays some random content in French.  That web page and content has nothing to do with me.

Answer (score 0):

Download the CLN source code from [here](https://www.ginac.de/CLN/), unpack it, and have a look into the `examples/` folder. Alternatively, you may browse the same folder using [gitweb](https://www.ginac.de/CLN/cln.git/?p=cln.git;a=tree;f=examples).